# Conditional expectations and Markov Processes

Tags: stochastic-calculus, finance, markov-process

I am doing a first pass of Stochastic Calculus from the text, *Stochastic calculus for finance, Volume I* by Steven Shreve. My aim is to learn computational skill, rather than deriving each result rigorously at this point.

In section 2.5 on [page 45](http://cms.dm.uba.ar/academico/materias/2docuat2016/analisis_cuantitativo_en_finanzas/Steve_Shreve_Stochastic_Calculus_for_Finance_I.pdf), Shreve first gives the following definition.

---

**Definition (Markov Process).** Consider the binomial market model. Let $(X_n)$ be a discrete stochastic process. $(X_n)$ is said to be Markov, if

\begin{align*}
(\forall n \in \mathbf{N})(\forall f(x))(\exists g(x))(\text{s.t.}\mathbb{E}_n[f(X_{n+1})]=g(X_n))
\end{align*}

---

He then proves that the stock-price process $(S_t)$, where $t \in \mathbf{Z}_{+}$ is a discrete Markov process, which I follow.

He then derives a recursive algorithm for computing the price of a derivative whose payoff only depends on the terminal stock price $S_N$, as below.

I don't quite understand, how is the Markov property of $(S_n)$ being applied to the step in yellow. Any hints/suggestions here would be extremely helpful.

[image]

I understand, that derivative price process is a martingale, so I could use that for the deduction in the yellow step. But, that's besides the point. I don't get, how the Markov property is being applied.

Comment: https://quant.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Btw I think somehow there's some missing info here in particular the $\tilde E$ vs the regular $E$